# rails g scaffold が帰ってこない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

mac で、 rails の開発をしようとしています。 `rails new kaikei --database=mysql` でプロジェクトを作成した後に、 cd して、 g scaffold しようとしたところ、コマンドが帰ってきませんでした。

```
% bundle exec rails g scaffold account_title name:string
^C/Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `verify_server_version'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:62:in `run'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:42:in `warm_run'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `call'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:24:in `call'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/Repositories/kaikei/bin/spring:15:in `require'
        from /Users/yukiinoue/Repositories/kaikei/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

bundle exec rails s などは、問題なく実行され、 rails の `Yay! You’re on Rails!` 画面が表示されています。なので、一体何が原因なのか、ちょっと分からないな、と感じている状態です。

#### 質問:

- どうして、 g scaffold が実行できないのでしょうか?

#### 補足:

環境は以下の通りです。

- 端末: terminal.app + tmux
- シェル: zsh

上記のログは、コマンド入力直後に何も反応がないので<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>で停止割り込みをかけた際に発生するエラーメッセージです。

Comment: CTRL+Cで割り込み停止させた際のエラーメッセージですよね？見た感じ、キーボードからの入力待ちの状態で停止しているように見受けられます。どのターミナルソフトで実行したのでしょうか？

Comment: @itmammoth 質問に補足情報を追記いたしました。

Comment: springを一度停止して再度実行してみるとどうでしょう？ `bin/spring stop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails new testapp`してごそごそした後にこれを一回削除し、もう一度`rails new testapp`すると、前に実行されたspringが残っているが使用できない状態になります。

springのプロセス探してkillしてください。

私は乱暴にcronで`pkill -KILL -f spring`を夜中に実行してます。

---

#### 質問者追記

おそらく、これが発生していた様子です。 `bin/spring stop` で解消しました。 itmammoth さんのコメントも参考にいたしました。ありがとうございました。